# What are the advantages of analyzing temperature in Kelvin?

Tags: temperature, data-analysis

I have air temperature data from reanalysis that I want to analyze. The reanalysis data is in Kelvin, so I'm wondering why they use Kelvin. Is there any advantage or difference in analyzing temperature data as Kelvin? or is it the same as Celsius? Which one would be better if the temperature range goes from -35 to 20?

thank you!

Comment: Are you asking specifically about measuring temperatures here on Earth, or just temperatures in general? If the latter, then this is probably a better fit over on the Physics SE community, though I expect it's already been asked there.

Comment: Thank you @Bill Oertell, it is air temperature from reanalysis data, I'll add it to my question.

Comment: You don't have to worry about minus signs :-)

Comment: Kelvin makes thermodynamic calculations much simpler- instead of adding 273.15 and complicating equations that are already relatively complicated, a simple change of units simplifies the problem.

Comment: It's the scientific standard to use SI units, and they're doing so, allowing people to be comfortable in what to expect.  Of course models generally [can't manage to provide flux data that fits intuition](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/10469/how-to-calculate-3-hour-flux-values-in-era-interim), so it only goes so far.  (Kelvin is the SI standard because it's based on more something fundamental, absolute zero, the lack of any energy).  So no particular advantage except trying to maintain standardization (and perhaps the small benefit of no negatives).

Comment: There is also a problem when you calculate the difference between two temperatures. Assume T1=293.15 K=20°C, T2=294.15 K=21°C => delta T = 1K = -272.15 °C. But at the same Time 21 [unit] - 20 [unit] should be 1 [unit] but it isn't: 21 °C - 20 °C = 1 K = -272.15 °C ... .

Comment: As others note, it's because Kelvin is an absolute unit, not a graded unit: 500K is literally twice as warm as 250K, but 500C isn't twice as warm as 250C (and the same is true for 250F and even the Rankin scale). You can divide Kelvins in the Ideal Gas Law (for example), but not graded temperature units.